# Offline.js - Multi-language

Tags: javascript, offline.js

I am use [Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/). Offline.js is a library to automatically alert your users when they've lost internet connectivity.

The Offline.js [provide](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline/tree/master/themes) the different language in the css file but each one language contains his css file.

In my website I detect user language and I show the words in his language for a good user experience.

Can you adapt this library for that?

Thanks

Comment: You mean dynamically change the language file loaded by Offline.js, using code external to Offline.js's code?

Comment: I want to find a way to dynamically change the language. I did not see offline.js has that feature

Comment: see https://github.com/HubSpot/offline/issues/155

Comment: As mentioned in @KyleFalconer's comment, you can dynamically load the language-appropriate CSS file or create it dynamically using `document.createElement('style')`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try with your solutions.

Comment: then load the particular language css file only after detecting the language using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you use less, you can import contextualize the css like this:

```
@import (inline) '../../bower_components/offline/themes/offline-theme-default.css';

.language-de {
  @import (less) '../../bower_components/offline/themes/offline-language-german.css';
}

.language-en {
  @import (less) '../../bower_components/offline/themes/offline-language-english.css';
}
```

You can then switch the language by setting the language-... class on your `<body>` element for example.

UPDATE: If you use the cleancss tool, make sure that you add '@charset "UTF-8";' in your main LESS file... otherwise there will be an @charset inside a block and cleanncss will mess up your CSS.

UPDATE: SASS can import css as well. Like that:

```
@import '../../bower_components/offline/themes/offline-theme-default';

.language-de {
  @import '../../bower_components/offline/themes/offline-language-german';
}

.language-en {
  @import '../../bower_components/offline/themes/offline-language-english';
}
```